# how to create a dictionary having different number of values at different keys?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, indexing

**Question.1 )** I want to create a dictionary , it consist of 8 keys , some keys has 2 values and some keys have 3 values. how to create this kinda dictionary in python.

i been trying using nested loops , but my logic  didn't worked.

**Desired output**

```
dict_a = { 1:[0,1], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5], 4:[6,7], 5:[8,9], 6:[10,11], 7:[12,13,14], 8:[15,16,17] }
```

**Question.2 )** If we successfully create the `dict_a` then,  In the second part, i want to merge the multiple values of dict_a according to the dict_b,shown below.

**for example :-**  In `dict_b = { 1:[1,2], 2:[2,3]......}` ,Here `1:[1,2]` means  I want to merge 1st and 2nd 'values' of dict_a dictionary, which will give me `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. similarly `2:[2,3]` will give me `[2,3,4,5]`

```
dict_b = { 1:[1,2], 2:[2,3], 3:[3,4], 4:[4,5], 5:[5,6], 6:[6,7], 7:[7,8] }
```

I actually tried the above method successfully, but for two keys `7th`and `8th` in `dict_a` , i want to merge with first two values only, i.e when `dict_b` goes to it's 7th key `7:[7,8]`, i want the result to be `[12,13,15,16]` and not `[12,13,14,15,16,17].`

but the method i used below will merge all inevitably.

```
dict_a = { 1:[0,1], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5], 4:[6,7], 5:[8,9], 6:[10,11], 7:[12,13,14], 8:[15,16,17] }

dict_b = { 1:[1,2], 2:[2,3], 3:[3,4], 4:[4,5], 5:[5,6], 6:[6,7], 7:[7,8] }

a_list = []

for i in dict_b:
    tem = []
    a_list.append(tem)
    for j in dict_b[i]:
        tem.extend(dict_a[j])
    print(tem)
```

**Desired output-**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[10, 11, 12, 13]
[12, 13, 15, 16]
```

Comment: Regarding making a dictionary with different numbers of values, there's no restriction against this in python. Post your code to create this dictionary, as the bug is probably in your nested loops.

Comment: The keys in a dictionary should be a type that implements `__hash__`, e.g. hashable. If you need keys with 2 or 3 values, use a 2 or 3 tuple, they are hashable, e.g.  `d=dict(); d[(1,2)]=1`should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to merge with the first 2 values, use a slice.

Change

```
tem.extend(dict_a[j])
```

to

```
tem.extend(dict_a[j][:2])
```